# Programmatically resizing EditText on orientation change

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, android-orientation

I'm trying to programmatically resize an `EditText` when the orientation of the phone changes, here's what I have so far:

```
private final float editTextWidthLandscap = 380;
private final float editTextWidthPortrait = 220;

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    Resources r = getResources();
    float px;
    if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        px = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, editTextWidthLandscap, r.getDisplayMetrics());
        input.setWidth((int) px); // input is an EditText 
        Toast.makeText(this, "landscape", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
        px = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, editTextWidthPortrait, r.getDisplayMetrics());
        input.setWidth((int) px);  // input is an EditText
        Toast.makeText(this, "portrait", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

I also have this in my manifest file (in case it matters):

```
    <activity
        android:name=".Results"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" >
    </activity>
```

The strange thing is that it displays the `Toast` just fine but it seems to ignore the `input.setWidth()` statement. If anyone could explain why the `EditText` is not being resized and/or give me pointers as to how i would be able to this correctly it would be greatly appreciated.

**Edit:**

This is a part of the XML file in which the EditText resides

```
    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:background="@color/purple"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/input"
        android:layout_width="220dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@drawable/search_bar"
        android:hint="@string/input_hint"
        android:inputType="text|textNoSuggestions"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:minHeight="50dp"
        android:minWidth="220dp"
        android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="@color/black_grey"
        android:textSize="16.67sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/search_button"
        android:layout_width="65dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@drawable/search_button" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**Edit 2: (solution)**

I still don't know what `input.setWidth()` does exactly but i found out i had to use `LayoutParams` for this issue. Below is the code that is working for me now:

```
    private final float editTextWidthLandscap = 380;
    private final float editTextWidthPortrait = 220;
    private final float editTextHeight = 50;

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        Resources r = getResources();
        float widthpx;
        float heightpx = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, editTextHeight, r.getDisplayMetrics());;
        if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
            widthpx = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, editTextWidthLandscap, r.getDisplayMetrics());
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams((int) Math.round(widthpx), (int) Math.round(heightpx));
            trademarkTextfield.setLayoutParams(lp);
        } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
            widthpx = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, editTextWidthPortrait, r.getDisplayMetrics());
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams((int) Math.round(widthpx), (int) Math.round(heightpx));
            trademarkTextfield.setLayoutParams(lp);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You don't show it here, but maybe you have defined layout_width as fill_parent for the EditText? This might override your setWidth().

Comment: Good suggestion, unfortunatly the EditText already had a number as width. Updated the post though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my own experience, sometimes we tend to overthink the reason for a bad behavior. I found more than once that things that I took for granted, were not so.

You should check that the px argument for the two cases are really different. I know this is a basics, but maybe `applyDimension` is not working the way you expect or there is some minimum width defined elsewhere and you just hit it.

You should also call `getWidth()` before and after the call to `setWidth()`. Why? because maybe the function is working and the system does think the width haschanged and the problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks for your insights, this made me look at my code in a different way and eventually led me to the solution (which was to use `LayoutParams` instead of `input.setWidth()`). I updated my post with the working code.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure why the size isnt changing programmatically, however, you may instead want to use a different layout file for landscape mode.  Just create a new folder called 'layout-land' and put your layout.xml file in there (with the same ids and filename) and change the sizes accordingly.

This may not be this best solution depending on your case, but its just another option...

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have tried this, but if i have the following line in my manifest it simply will not use the layout that is in the layout-land folder. It will just use the layout that is already displayed for both portrait and landscape.

`android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"`

I have another class which doesn't use that line and the layout-land folder works just fine for that